# Set axios request headers of an existing instance

Tags: reactjs, axios

I have an axios interceptor for my react application that within I want to conditionally apply an authorization header to (some of the services are hitting internal services that need the auth header, others are outside and fail with it included). I see on the axios repo you can easily create the instance with the headers included like so:

```
var instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://some-domain.com/api/',
  timeout: 1000,
  headers: {'X-Custom-Header': 'foobar'}
});
```

but in that case, the header will always be included. Inside of my interceptor I have tried a few attempts like:

```
axios.interceptors.request.use(function ( config ) {
  if ( serviceRequiresToken(config.url) ) {
    config.headers[ config.method ] = {'Authorization': this.props.userData.token.authorizationHeader};
  }
  return config;
}, function ( error ) {
  return Promise.reject(error);
});
```

but when I use this the call is never made (I don't get 403's or anything, it just doesn't send a request). I also tried like `config.headers.push({'auth..':'...'})` but that was a similar situation.

Comment: I don't see you are returning the promise. Take a look at this link https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/266 comment from mzabriskie Jul 16, 2016. I think this could work.